# Get Instagram express permissions (scope)

Tags: authentication, permissions, token, instagram

I'm trying to get `comments` `likes` `relationships` permissions from my Instagram app but i only get `basic` permission 
i am using this token authentication URL:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=XX&response_type=code&scope=likes+comments+relationships
```

which there is another app using same URL and it give me `comments` `likes` `relationships` permissions

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply for access here: https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/contact/185819881608116

by default u only get basic permissions. `comments` `likes` `relationships` require special approval from Instagram.